# ABNT2 keyboard in Ubuntu Studio 16.04: accented letters only in terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I just installed Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS.

If I type (say) `~` and then `a`, I get

- `~a` if I work in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)
- `ã` if I work in GUI mode (include terminal emulator)

How can I force Xfce to use whatever works properly in terminal mode?

Comment: You need to select that layout but with the "dead keys" option.

Comment: `setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2 -option deadkeys`
Like that?

Comment: I don't know the command, I always use GUI for that and I don't run XFCE.

Comment: I guess Brazilian layouts are "with deadkeys" by default, because there is only one option with "without deadkeys" description in the XFCE keyboard configurer. I've found the page below which makes me think that that is a bug in Ubuntu 16.04.
http://ubuntuforum-br.org/index.php?topic=119923.0
The thread isn't solved yet, so I guess my best option is `dist-upgrade` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work using this command from terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

It would display a little wizard for setting up keyboard layout preferences.

For ABNT Brazilian Keyboard, select "**Generic 105-key PC (intl)**".

This tool will update the file **/etc/default/keyboard** with your preferences.